# Change colour of specific streets on the map in ios

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps-sdk-ios, heremaps, heremaps-ios-sdk

I have an iOS app with a map where the user can see roads of different colors with a specific meaning.

> For example - Show some roads red which has a particular meaning and
>   some roads green which has a different meaning etc. so that the user
>   will see the map with color-coded roads.

All I have is the name of the road and the color which has to be assigned to the road from the API.

I am aware of Google Maps Platform Styling Wizard but that changes the color of all the roads in the map whereas I want to set the color to only specific roads and that also in different colors as required.

Is it possible to achieve this using Google maps or Here maps? 
Any suggestions would really be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to acomplish this.

1. Add a polyline over the streets that you want to change colours of. More details can be found [here.](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/shapes)
2. Not useful if you want to modify only certain roads, but the [Google Maps Styling Wizard.](https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com) is an option.

Comment: Sorry, I dont have coordinates. I just have a street name. and I want to change the color of a specific street(full street). Using Google API I am just getting only center  coordinates of street,

Comment: To get the coordinates, you would go on to www.maps.google.com , drop a pin where you want to get the coordinates and a small pop-up shows up at the bottom with the Street name and number under that is where you would find the coordinates. Get the coordinates at every place of the street where it turns and use the code in the documentation to add the Polyline in.

Comment: Ya thanks. I can do that but I have 15K street names :-(